# gamma distribution to chi squared transform

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, transformation, gamma-distribution

I thought If X~gamma($\alpha$, $\beta$) then $\frac{2X}{\alpha}$ ~ $\chi^2_n$ where n=2$\beta$. but when I solve exercise in Mathematical statistics with application (ex9.85e)
If Y~Gamma$(\alpha$, $\theta$) then $\frac{2Y}{\alpha}$ should follow $\chi^2_{2\theta}$ ? but, my professor said $\frac{2Y}{\alpha}$ follow $\chi^2_{4n}$. why is that?! Am i missing something right?

Comment: Oops. My mistake. Yes Mathematical statistics with application by Dennis Wackerly

Comment: Could you make an example? It's quite tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The textbook mentioned was confirmed (via comments, deleted afterwards, back in Dec. 2016) to be by Dennis Wackerly et al*

There's probably a mix up of the parameters when trying to recall the functional form by memory. The transformation of dividing by a parameter should be dividing the scale parameter $\beta$. Both statements as posted here by the professor and by you are "off" in that respect.

##### Parameters Clarification

There are two common parameterizations for Gamma distribution so just to be clear, here $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ means

$$f_X(u) = \frac1{\beta} \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left( \frac{u}{\beta} \right)^{\alpha - 1}e^{ -\frac{u}{\beta}}$$

written in such form to emphasize the role played by the scaling parameter $\beta$, where $\alpha$ is the shape parameter.

(the other common parametrization is the use of $\lambda = 1/\beta$ as the rate of a Poisson process)

One can view a Chi-square distribution as defined by taking $\alpha = \frac{n}2$ and $\beta = 2$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the degree of freedom. That is, Chi-sq is a special case of Gamma. This is what Dennis Wackerly's book does in Sec.4.6 on p.187 (or the corresponding place where Gamma distribution is introduced in other editions).

Chi-sq distribution can of course be defined with different motivations. Regardless of how it is constructed, the density for a $S \sim \chi^2_n$ takes the form

$$f_S(u) = \frac12 \frac1{\Gamma(\frac{n}2)}\left( \frac{u}2 \right)^{ \frac{n}2 - 1}e^{ -\frac{u}2}$$

##### Answer to the Stated Question

Now, back to examining our $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$. Define a scaled version $W\equiv \frac{2X}{\beta}$ such that the inverse transform is $x = h(w) = \frac{\beta}2 w$

$$
\begin{align}
f_W(u) &=  \bigg| \frac{ \text{d} h(u) }{ \text{d} u} \bigg|\cdot f_X\left( h(u) \right) \\
&= \frac{\beta}2 \cdot \frac1{\beta} \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left( \frac{ \beta u}{2\beta} \right)^{\alpha - 1}e^{ -\frac{\beta u}{2\beta}} \\
&= \frac12 \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left( \frac{u}2 \right)^{\alpha - 1}e^{ -\frac{u}2}
\end{align}$$

which gives the Chi-sq distribution when $\alpha$ is a half-integer (which includes integers), that is, a subset of such $W$ gives $W \sim \chi_n^2$ when $\alpha = \frac{n}2$.

Note that one can have a set of (collection of) Chi-sq with arbirary jumps in degree of freedom. In particular,

- when $\alpha$ is any even-integers, $\alpha = 2m$, this subset of $W  = \frac{2X}{\beta}$ gives $W \sim \chi^2_m$ where $m$ is any natural number.
- when $\alpha$ is any multiple of four, $\alpha = 4m$ for integer $m$, the subset of $W  = \frac{2X}{\beta}$ gives us $W \sim \chi^2_{2m}$ only the even degrees of freedom.

One can say that you were right and the professor was wrong (besides the parameters mix-up).

It can also be seen that any attempt to change the degree of freedom in the transformation will fail: the shape parameter $\alpha$ appears in the exponent in the density so, if the goal is to replace $\alpha$ by something else, first one must make $\alpha$ disappear via incorporating some transformation that involves power, like $W \equiv X^{\alpha-1}$. However, besides the Jacobian term bringing back the $\alpha$, that power will ruin the $e^{-u}$ term and will not give you a Chi-sq.